# PHP $_POST from select box returns only the first character

Tags: php, post, drop-down-menu, smarty

i want to post values from a select box, run them through PHP and assign them to a Smarty object.

My html markup is the following:

```
<form action="http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=presse" method="post">
<p><label for="startDate" class="search-label">Jahr:</label>
<select name="datepicker">
   <option value="2014">2014</option>
   <option value="2013">2013</option>
   <option value="2012">2012</option>
</select></p>
<select name="issue">
   <option value="Abisolierzange">Abisolierzange</option>
   <option value="International">International</option>
   <option value="Kabelmesser">Kabelmesser</option>
</select></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit_presse_filter" class="blockHeadline" value="Suchen">
</form>
```

I receive the form data like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_presse_filter'])) {
    $date  = $_REQUEST['datepicker'];   
    $issue = $_REQUEST['issue'];    
    $search_results["issue"]["datum"] = $date;
    $search_results["issue"]["ueberschrift"] = $issue;
}
```

And finaly in my template i put out the data like this:

```
{search_result.date}
{search_result.ueberschrift}
```

But i will only get the first letters of the values, like

```
2
```

for the date and

```
 A
```

for the first value of the issue.

Why is that?

**EDIT:**

The mistake was within the smarty foreach clause.

In php i build in a counter like this:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
$number = mysql_num_rows($result);

$search_results = array();

if($number > 0) {
$i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $search_results["issue"][$i]["datum"] = $row['datum'];
        $search_results["issue"][$i]["ueberschrift"] = $row['ueberschrift'];
        $search_results["issue"][$i]["inhalt"] = $row['inhalt1'];
        $search_results["issue"][$i++]["ort"] = $row['ort'];

    }
}
$smarty->assign('search_results', $search_results);
```

Now i can do this in my template:

```
{if $search_results.issue}
   <p><strong>Presse</strong></p>
   <ul>
    {foreach item=search_result from=$search_results.issue}
    <li>
        <h2>{$search_result.datum}</h2>
    </li>
    {/foreach}  
    </ul>
 {/if}
```

Comment: try this -  `$date  = $_POST['datepicker'];   
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];`

Comment: this normally happens when you are accessing a string position as opposed to an array index

Comment: Add a debug output to the `if(isset($_POST...` part of your code to see if `$date` and `$issue` contain the values you want (they should from what I see here). Then you know if your problem is with the HTML-POST-PHP part or only a PHP internal coding mistake.

Comment: How about `{search_result.issue.date} {search_result.issue.ueberschrift}` ? You forgot the `issue` array key/level in you template

Comment: What values are you getting in `$_POST`?

Comment: The values i receive are correct! I also tried with $_POST instead of $_REQUEST. @verbumSapienti how to i solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a two-dimensional array here: `$search_results["issue"]["datum"] = $date;`
Maybe you want that to be `$search_results["datum"] = $date;` instead. Then `{search_result.date}` should work. Otherwise maybe `{search_result.issue.date}` helps.

Comment: Because i start my template part with. {foreach item=search_result from=$search_results.issue} it is correct. I also get an ouput but just the first character of the value.

Comment: @PascalCloverfield Please post that part of your code too then. And the debug output from my comment above as well.

Comment: You pointed me to the right place. I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. From the code you are posting here I get the impression that you could completely remove all references to `["issue"]` and `.issue` and it should work too. Or are you anywhere using `$search_results["something_else"]` or `$search_results.something_else` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, i'm going to use something else there later. But thanks. :)